# How to detect under surface crop maturity or stress using satellite images?

Tags: image, satellite

I need to detect under surface crop maturity or stress using satellite images.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way initially is to use NDVI or Normalized Difference Vegetation Index, which is a fairly simple formula for the ratio of some somewhat standardized wavelength measurements: (Near InfraRed (NIR) - Red ) / (NIR+Red) .  There are variations on this for each satellite as they all seem to use slightly different bands.  There are also adjustments that many folks have made for particular crops and uses, but this gives a basic metric to track stress and maturity.  For the crop of interest, you'll need to do some digging to see what particular maturation curves look like in the region of interest (yes, different regions display different growth curves). The following link shows how to do this with Landsat images: [USGS Link](https://www.usgs.gov/land-resources/nli/landsat/landsat-normalized-difference-vegetation-index?qt-science_support_page_related_con=0#qt-science_support_page_related_con)